# how to resolve CommonKeyDerivation.h: no such file found error

Tags: iphone, aes, commoncrypto

I am encrypting a string and use #import CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h but xcode show error no such file found though I add security framework and I also use #import CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h but it shows no error.

I found file in openSource but not found any idea to use it in my code or download

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show ur code, and, do you really have that file u r importing, into your bundle?

Answer (score 0):

change your import statement to:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
```